# Is it possible to include wiki markup in MediaWiki searches?

Tags: search, wikipedia, mediawiki

I tried to find improperly formatted URLs on Wikipedia by entering for [a search query with wiki markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&profile=advanced&search=%3Cref%3Ehttp://&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&redirs=1&profile=advanced), but this doesn't return matches of this markup in Wikipedia. Does Wikipedia have any search options that make it possible to include wiki markup in searches?

The search query that I entered was `<ref>http://`, and no results showed up for matches of this markup.

Comment: I see you've asked quite a few Wikipedia questions here. While they're perfectly on-topic, and certainly I wouldn't want to chase you away, there is _huge_ and active community of folks _at Wikipedia_ who are probably a better resource for your questions.

Comment: @AlEverett Unfortunately, Wikipedia's talk pages don't have any kind of notification system for replies to comments that are left there. This makes it somewhat unreliable as a discussion forum, since it's hard for users to find replies to their questions.

Comment: You could always "Watch" the page, but I know what you mean.

Comment: And here we are, chasing questions on SE as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can, with regex search: [`insource:/\<ref\>http:\/\//`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=insource%3A%2F%5C%3Cref%5C%3Ehttp%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%2F&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&profile=advanced) (use with care).

More information at [Help:CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch).

Comment: is cirrus required? or is regex search supported by MW core?

Comment: MediaWiki core has no regex search.

Comment: Thx, do you know of any extension or method besides Cirrus which does? Cirrus requires Elastica, which requires Java, which is not available on my shared web-hosting. My requirement is to work on shared web-hosting.

Comment: @johnywhy No, I don't think such an extension exists. Unless your wiki is extremely small, a regex search on MySQL could be very stressful for your database and application server. Can you use Sphinx? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Search_extensions

Comment: Will check out Spinx, thx. Actually, just trying to find transclusions of a specific template with a specific parameter, eg: {{Color|Green}}. I need to display the search-results as a list on any page, without any search-controls.

Comment: @johnywhy there might be extensions which add special pages to produce such lists.

Comment: Yes, DPL. But it cannot find pipes or transclusion parameters. Same with MediaWiki Url API.